# File accesses fail inside in-process COM server compiled with VS2013, with access-violation in release build

Tags: security, file-io, visual-studio-2013, com

I am attempting to use a C++ COM server compiled with VS2013.  It appears unable to access local files when compiled as 'Release'.  By contrast it exhibits no problems with local file access when compiled as 'Debug' or when compiled using VS2010.  Both the COM client and COM server are compiled as 32-bit.  I haven't tested with VS2012.

In order to localise the problem, I used the following fragment of code:

```
{
    std::basic_ifstream<char, char_traits<char> >
        in_strm(L"P:\\pp\\1302\\Examples\\copy.pp", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);

    if (in_strm)
    {
        int x = 1;
        in_strm.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(int));
        bool result = (x == 0 && in_strm.good());
        in_strm.close();
    }
}
```

The above code works fine within the COM client, but throws an access violation with the following call-stack when executed within the COM server.

```
ntdll.dll!_RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection@8()   Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlEnterCriticalSection@4() Unknown
msvcr120.dll!_lock_file(_iobuf * pf) Line 223   C
ConvertServer13001.dll!std::basic_filebuf<char,std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock() Line 353   C++
msvcp120d.dll!std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::_Sentry_base::_Sentry_base(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> > & _Istr={...}) Line 97  C++
msvcp120d.dll!std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> > & _Istr={...}, bool _Noskip=true) Line 117  C++
msvcp120d.dll!std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::read(char * _Str=0x060bbea8, __int64 _Count=4) Line 730 C++
```

I have checked the "last error" in the Visual Studio debugger using "@err,hr", and no error is reported.  The local file definitely exists and is not read-only.

I suspect that Microsoft have added a new COM security setting that I must handle in a particular way.  Please could anyone advise me regarding this or anything else that might be an issue here?

Comment: Are you sure you're running Release on both of them.  The call stack shows msvcp120d.dll which is the Debug version of the C++ runtime DLL.

Comment: Great spot @JoeWillcoxson!  Yes, it was a release build, but someone (not me) had messed up the linker settings by adding in a new dependency on a debug library!  I can't say for sure that this'll fix it as I'm now having some trouble getting it to compile again, but I reckon there's a good chance.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @JoeWillcoxson, your tip was just what I needed.  I also discovered that _DEBUG was erroneously defined in the project's preprocessor definitions.